# Architectural Design for Globalizing ASP.NET application

Tags: architecture, globalization

This is an architecture related question. I am planning to globalize my website which typically involves following items to be globalized:
1. .aspx pages
2. .css files
3. images
4. dynamic content from DB
5. taking care of currency, datetime, right to left and left to right stuff.

I wanted to know for an enterprise application what are the best practices or approaches could be to achieve the above mentioned requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For aspx pages use resources (resx files)
For database use table with localized values (CultureId, Value) so string values are easily can be localized.

for what purpose there is need to localize css?